# Blockchain ipn not working?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i have perfect coding for blockchain . amount has been recieved on associated account but balance of user did not updated . please check if any error exists.
iam unable to understand why its happening. if any one can found error i will be grateful too you very much.
code for btc preview:

```
@extends('layouts.user')
@section('style')

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/dashboard/css/cus.css') }}">

@endsection
@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-shadow" data-collapsed="0"><!-- to apply shadow add class "panel-shadow" -->

                <!-- panel head -->
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-send"></i> <strong>{{ $page_title }}</strong></div>
                </div>

                <!-- panel body -->
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                                <div class="panel panel-info">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 style="font-size: 28px;"><b>
                                                @if($fund->payment_type == 1)
                                                    Paypal
                                                @elseif($fund->payment_type == 2)
                                                    Perfect Money
                                                @elseif($fund->payment_type == 3)
                                                    BTC - ( BlockChain )
                                                @else
                                                    Credit Card
                                                @endif
                                            </b></h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="font-size: 18px;padding: 18px;" class="panel-body text-center">
                                        @if($fund->payment_type == 1)
                                            @php $img = $payment->paypal_image @endphp
                                        @elseif($fund->payment_type == 2)
                                            @php $img = $payment->perfect_image @endphp
                                        @elseif($fund->payment_type == 3)
                                            @php $img = $payment->btc_image @endphp
                                        @else
                                            @php $img = $payment->stripe_image @endphp
                                        @endif
                                        <img width="100%" class="image-responsive" src="{{ asset('assets/images') }}/{{ $img }}" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <a href="{{ url('user/fund-add') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-icon icon-left"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back to Payment Method Page</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="panel panel-info panel-shadow" data-collapsed="0"><!-- to apply shadow add class "panel-shadow" -->

                                <!-- panel head -->
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> <strong>{{ $page_title }}</strong></div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- panel body -->
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <h3>Current Balance : <strong>{{ Auth::user()->amount }} - {{ $basic->currency }}</strong></h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <h4 style="text-align: center;"> SEND EXACTLY <strong>{{ $btc }} BTC </strong> TO <strong>{{ $add }}</strong><br>
                                            {!! $code !!} <br>
                                            <strong>SCAN TO SEND</strong> <br><br>
                                            <strong style="color: red;">NB: 3 Confirmation required to Credited your Account</strong>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!---ROW-->



@endsection
@section('scripts')


@endsection
```

here is ipn code:

```
public function btcIPN()
    {
        $depoistTrack = $_GET['invoice_id'];
        $secret = $_GET['secret'];
        $address = $_GET['address'];
        $value = $_GET['value'];
        $confirmations = $_GET['confirmations'];
        $value_in_btc = $_GET['value'] / 100000000;

        $trx_hash = $_GET['transaction_hash'];

        $DepositData = FundLog::whereTransaction_id($depoistTrack)->first();

        if ($DepositData->status == 0){

        if ($DepositData->btc_amo == $value_in_btc && $DepositData->btc_acc == $address && $secret=="ABIR" && $confirmations>2){

            $charge = $DepositData->fix + ($DepositData->amount * $DepositData->percent) / 100;
            $uuuu = User::findOrFail($DepositData->user_id);

            // Fun Create

            $fun['user_id'] = $DepositData->user_id;
            $fun['payment_type'] = 1;
            $fun['transaction_id'] = $DepositData->transaction_id;
            $fun['amount'] = $DepositData->amount;
            $fun['rate'] = $DepositData->rate;
            $fun['charge'] = $charge;
            $fun['total'] = $DepositData->btc_amo;
            Fund::create($fun);

            // User Log Create

            $us['user_id'] = $DepositData->user_id;
            $us['payment_type'] = 1;
            $us['derails'] = "Fund Add via BlockChain. Transaction id : # ".$DepositData->transaction_id;
            $us['balance'] = $DepositData->amount;
            $us['charge'] = $charge;
            $us['old_balance'] = $uuuu->amount;
            $us['new_balance'] = $DepositData->amount + $us['old_balance'];
            $uuuu->amount = $us['new_balance'];
            $uuuu->save();
            UserBalance::create($us);

            // Admin Log

            $bas = BasicSetting::first();
            $ad['user_id'] = $DepositData->user_id;
            $ad['payment_type'] = 3; //Blockchain
            $ad['transaction_id'] = $DepositData->transaction_id;
            $ad['balance'] = $DepositData->amount;
            $ad['details'] = "Fund Deposit via BlockChain. Transaction ID : # ".$DepositData->transaction_id;
            $ad['charge'] = $charge;
            $ad['old_balance'] = $bas->admin_total;
            $ad['new_balance'] = $bas->admin_total + $DepositData->amount + $charge;
            AdminBalance::create($ad);
            $bas->admin_total = $ad['new_balance'];
            $bas->save();

            session()->flash('message','Fund Successfully Deposit.');
                session()->flash('type','success');
                session()->flash('title','Success');
                return redirect()->route('add-fund');
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fix it try this.

```
@extends('layouts.user')
@section('style')

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/dashboard/css/cus.css') }}">

@endsection
@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-shadow" data-collapsed="0"><!-- to apply shadow add class "panel-shadow" -->

                <!-- panel head -->
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-send"></i> <strong>{{ $page_title }}</strong></div>
                </div>

                <!-- panel body -->
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                                <div class="panel panel-info">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 style="font-size: 28px;"><b>
                                                @if($fund->payment_type == 1)
                                                    Paypal
                                                @elseif($fund->payment_type == 2)
                                                    Perfect Money
                                                @elseif($fund->payment_type == 3)
                                                    BTC - ( BlockChain )
                                                @else
                                                    Credit Card
                                                @endif
                                            </b></h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="font-size: 18px;padding: 18px;" class="panel-body text-center">
                                        @if($fund->payment_type == 1)
                                            @php $img = $payment->paypal_image @endphp
                                        @elseif($fund->payment_type == 2)
                                            @php $img = $payment->perfect_image @endphp
                                        @elseif($fund->payment_type == 3)
                                            @php $img = $payment->btc_image @endphp
                                        @else
                                            @php $img = $payment->stripe_image @endphp
                                        @endif
                                        <img width="100%" class="image-responsive" src="{{ asset('assets/images') }}/{{ $img }}" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <a href="{{ url('user/fund-add') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-icon icon-left"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back to Payment Method Page</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="panel panel-info panel-shadow" data-collapsed="0"><!-- to apply shadow add class "panel-shadow" -->

                                <!-- panel head -->
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> <strong>{{ $page_title }}</strong></div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- panel body -->
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <h3>Current Balance : <strong>{{ Auth::user()->amount }} - {{ $basic->currency }}</strong></h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <h4 style="text-align: center;"> SEND EXACTLY <strong>{{ $btc }} BTC </strong> TO <strong>{{ $add }}</strong><br>
                                            {!! $code !!} <br>
                                            <strong>SCAN TO SEND</strong> <br><br>
                                            <strong style="color: red;">NB: 3 Confirmation required to Credited your Account</strong>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!---ROW-->



@endsection
@section('scripts')


@endsection

here is ipn code:

public function btcIPN()
    {
        $depoistTrack = $_GET['invoice_id'];
        $secret = $_GET['secret'];
        $address = $_GET['address'];
        $value = $_GET['value'];
        $confirmations = $_GET['confirmations'];
        $value_in_btc = $_GET['value'] / 100000000;

        $trx_hash = $_GET['transaction_hash'];

        $DepositData = FundLog::whereTransaction_id($depoistTrack)->first();

        if ($DepositData->status == 0){

        if ($DepositData->btc_amo == $value_in_btc && $DepositData->btc_acc == $address && $secret=="ABIR" && $confirmations>2){

            $charge = $DepositData->fix + ($DepositData->amount * $DepositData->percent) / 100;
            $uuuu = User::findOrFail($DepositData->user_id);

            // Fun Create

            $fun['user_id'] = $DepositData->user_id;
            $fun['payment_type'] = 1;
            $fun['transaction_id'] = $DepositData->transaction_id;
            $fun['amount'] = $DepositData->amount;
            $fun['rate'] = $DepositData->rate;
            $fun['charge'] = $charge;
            $fun['total'] = $DepositData->btc_amo;
            Fund::create($fun);

            // User Log Create

            $us['user_id'] = $DepositData->user_id;
            $us['payment_type'] = 1;
            $us['derails'] = "Fund Add via BlockChain. Transaction id : # ".$DepositData->transaction_id;
            $us['balance'] = $DepositData->amount;
            $us['charge'] = $charge;
            $us['old_balance'] = $uuuu->amount;
            $us['new_balance'] = $DepositData->amount + $us['old_balance'];
            $uuuu->amount = $us['new_balance'];
            $uuuu->save();
            UserBalance::create($us);

            // Admin Log

            $bas = BasicSetting::first();
            $ad['user_id'] = $DepositData->user_id;
            $ad['payment_type'] = 3; //Blockchain
            $ad['transaction_id'] = $DepositData->transaction_id;
            $ad['balance'] = $DepositData->amount;
            $ad['details'] = "Fund Deposit via BlockChain. Transaction ID : # ".$DepositData->transaction_id;
            $ad['charge'] = $charge;
            $ad['old_balance'] = $bas->admin_total;
            $ad['new_balance'] = $bas->admin_total + $DepositData->amount + $charge;
            AdminBalance::create($ad);
            $bas->admin_total = $ad['new_balance'];
            $bas->save();

            session()->flash('message','Fund Successfully Deposit.');
                session()->flash('type','success');
                session()->flash('title','Success');
                return redirect()->route('add-fund');
        }
        }
    }
```